# Async Await not working on states from useStates of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an onClick function to delete an item. 
When the user clicks that button, the state `deletedItem` will be assigned with that item. 
Here is the code:

```
<button 
  type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-black white-text"
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove item"
  onClick={ 
    async () => {
      await setDeletedItem(item.name);
      console.log(deletedItem);
      deleteCartItem()
    }
  }>x</button>
```

But the state are not immediately changed after clicking a button. It was one-value delayed which makes the item that I want to delete so inaccurate. And I have other async/await functions and setting states in the same React using classes, but they work fine. Is there something wrong with this or how to solve this?

Comment: You have to use second form of setState when you're using setState that depends on the previous state. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: I don't think deletedItem depends on the previous state since it will just be assigned to whatever the name of the clicked item is, isn't it? @boosted_duck

Answer (score 2):

In order to `async-await` syntaxes to work correctly, you need to use them with functions that return promises.

Since state updater function from react-hooks, doesn't return a promise, it may or may not work. Same is the case with setState function in class components

The solution here is to make use of useEffect that runs on state change, you can call whatever function you need to call in response to state change in this method

Comment: I do get your idea, but this variable assignment is inside a `map` and I am setting a state depending on the user selection and only when the user clicks it. 

`{items.map(item => {item.name} {item.price} <button onClick={setSelectedItem(item.name)}}` 
So, I am doing like this, and the state assignment cannot just go out of the scope of the `map`. Or is there a better way to do this? I need to return a selectedItem's name to the php backend so it knows which item to be deleted. @Shubham Khatri

Answer (score 0):

**setState** can accept a callback function, to do anything with the state variable after it is updated.

Unfortunately **useState** doesn't have a *callback feature*. Inside a function it always gets executed at the end, no matter how many async/await you use.

That's why **useEffect** is there to rescue. You need to call your php backend(deleteCartItem) inside an useEffect.

*And YES, usage async/await are better limited to Promises only.*

I have tried this. You can see for yourself.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-await-not-working-on-states-from-usestates-of-react-99i41