# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in a react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Getting this error in onSubmit() function.

[image]

this is not accessible within onSubmit() function.
I have also added `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);` but still it is not working.

Code :

```js
...
class CamapaignNew extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {minimumContribution : ''};
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    onSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(this);
        const minC = this.state.minimumContribution;
        await factory.methods.createCampaign(minC).send({
            from: accounts[0]
        });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <label>Minimum Contribution</label>
                        <Input 
                            label="wei" 
                            labelPosition='right' 
                            value={this.state.minimumContribution}
                            onChange={(event) => {this.setState({ minimumContribution: event.target.value })}}
                        />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button primary>Create!</Button>
                </Form>
           ...
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding vs Arrow-function (in JavaScript, or for react onClick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375440/binding-vs-arrow-function-in-javascript-or-for-react-onclick)

Comment: Shouldn't you have something like `const [state, setState] = useState({minimumContribution: ''})`?

Comment: Its not using functional component @GACy20

Comment: Fortunately, I got the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595506/async-await-not-working-on-states-from-usestates-of-react